# How to plot a pie chart in matplotlib with 3 columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, pie-chart

I need to plot a pie chart using matplotlib but my `DataFrame` has 3 columns namely `gender`, `segment` and `total_amount`.
I have tried playing with `plt.pie()` arguments but it only takes x and labels for data. I tried setting `gender` as a legend but then it doesn't look right.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': {0: 'Female',
  1: 'Female',
  2: 'Female',
  3: 'Male',
  4: 'Male',
  5: 'Male'},
 'Segment': {0: 'Gold',
  1: 'Platinum',
  2: 'Silver',
  3: 'Gold',
  4: 'Platinum',
  5: 'Silver'},
 'total_amount': {0: 2110045.0,
  1: 2369722.0,
  2: 1897545.0,
  3: 2655970.0,
  4: 2096445.0,
  5: 2347134.0}})

plt.pie(data = df,x="claim_amount",labels="Segment")
plt.legend(d3.gender)
plt.show()
```

The result I want is a pie chart of `total_amount` and its labels as `gender` and `segment`. If I can get the percentage, it will be a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```py
# Data to plot
# Take the information from the segment and label columns and join them into one string
labels = df["Segment"]+ " " + df["gender"].map(str)
# Extract the sizes of the segments
sizes = df["total_amount"]
# Plot with labels and percentage
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels,autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

You should get this:
[image]